# SASL authorisation and hostname to access the server

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sasl

I have a working postfix mail server. It is registered under two DNS names: mail.xxxx.de and xxxx.no-ip.org. I use SASL via dovecot for relay authorisation. It works flawless when the client uses the latter name to access the mail server. However, it fails when the first is used.

> Aug 06 14:53:37 mail postfix/smtpd[73670]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xx.xx.xx.xx]: 554 5.7.1 xx@xx.com: Relay access denied; from=<eckart.xxxx@xxx.de to=xx@xx.com proto=ESMTP helo=<smtpclient.apple>

I am unable to identify on which parameter it depends which one works.

I would like to achieve that both options are working.

Comment: This is sending mail? Dovecot doesn't generally apply when sending, it handles IMAP/POP. Look at how you have Postfix's SMTPAuth set up.

Comment: @tsc_chazz: Dovecot provides SASL for Postfix; see [Postfix SASL Howto](https://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) & [Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/).

Comment: But this question still needs a lot more details including the Postfix's configuration.